# How did col get converted to str type?

Tags: python, string

Converting a pre-existing list of int to str for use with a dictionary
The following code (Scribus but surely irrelevant) produces messages...

```
int -- int
str -- int
str -- int
str -- str ***
```

Why on the second loop is col a str type?

```
for col in person:
    num=col
    scribus.messageBox("",str(type(num))+"--"+str(type(col)))
    num=str(num)
    scribus.messageBox("",str(type(num))+"--"+str(type(col)))
    if num not in personlist:
        num="0"
    person[col]=num
    scribus.messageBox("",str(type(num))+"--"+str(type(col)))
```

Comment: well, what's in `person`?

Comment: Interesting behavior. Can you provide a full code sample that reproduces your problem? Preferably one that uses `print` instead of `messageBox`.

Comment: Sorry, person is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. or similar Code is too long to include an easy example but the dictionary (probably irrelevant) is simply int keys and access lists in the simplest way. The messagebox is the equiv. of print and just gives a debug message. I guess print type(num) etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
person[col]=num
```

If you're trying to replace the currently-being-iterated-over value in `person` with `num`, this won't work. `col` is the value inside the list, not the index of the value in the list. For example, in the first iteration, `col` is 1, so `person[col]=num` modifies the second element in `person` rather than the first. If you want the index, use `enumerate`.

```
for idx, col in enumerate(person):
    num=col
    scribus.messageBox("",str(type(num))+"--"+str(type(col)))
    num=str(num)
    scribus.messageBox("",str(type(num))+"--"+str(type(col)))
    if num not in personlist:
        num="0"
    person[idx]=num
    scribus.messageBox("",str(type(num))+"--"+str(type(col)))
```

Comment: I am very grateful for this response, these matters are always down to a lack of proper understanding. SOLVED!